# Answer to an email I didn't send

Tags: communication, colleagues, email, coworking

I've got one coworker from my company (working in another location than mine) who sent me an email as if I had already asked him something, but I didn't send any mail to him. I don't know him at all.

How can I tell him in a polite way that I don't understand what he is talking about?

Comment: Is there something about the relationship between your two offices or this person in particular that makes you so concerned about not being seen as polite? Do you get a lot of feedback that your email comes across as impolite? This person could have very easily selected your name from an email list by accident.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By far the preferred option is:

- Reply to his email, with the comment that he has perhaps sent it to you instead of his intended recipient, as that is almost certainly what has happened.

Comment: If you want to be professional, always reply.

Comment: Not necessarily - in some organisations, that would cause trouble, which is why I included it as an option.

Comment: I will answer to him, i think in fact he sent it to the wrong people.

Comment: moffeltje - there are more types of people/teams/organisations out there than I ever imagined. If you have not encountered that type of culture, then be glad :-)

Comment: Deleting is not such a good idea if the sender expects a reply. It's to the point and it's more considerate to reply  that you were not the one who asked the question and you have no idea what to do with the answer. Your  reply might trigger the idea that he is sending to the wrong party.

Comment: for those of you who haven't seen those environments, I have updated the post to clarify.

Comment: @RoryAlsop If it is obvious by the email content that a reply is expected would you recommend a phone call requesting clarification for strict securtiy environments?

Comment: @RoryAlsop - surely, in these "strict security environments", the professional approach would be reply only to the sender informing that you have received an email you think you shouldn't have, with assurances of deletion, and then delete. Otherwise, you've just allowed a potential ongoing security breach.

Comment: I have removed the contentious option, as it seems to generate unnecessary discussion.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I was actualy looking for an expansion on that option.  I've never worked in an environment like that so I'm quite curious.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I tell him in a polite way that I don't understand what he is
>   talking about?

Just respond in a polite way.

"Sorry, Mr. Coworker.

When reading through this email, it seems that you feel as if I asked you X. I think there may be some confusion, as I don't recall doing that."

Answer (score 2):

This happens quite often.  Maybe there is another person with a similar name and they misentered.  I would say - "hi there.  Was this note intended for me?"